# Django - Unpack dictionary in include

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I want to unpack a dictionary in an include tag.

```
# Python
kwargs = {"dictionary": "vertical"}

# Template
{% include "test.html" with kwargs %}

{# This should be turned into this #} 
{% include "test.html" with dictionary=vertical %}
```

Is this possible using **only** an inclusing tag?